# is there any way to enlarge the font of menu bar and prompt windows in matlab

Tags: java, linux, matlab, ubuntu, fonts

i have a laptop with a high resolution. i installed ubuntu(a linux distro) on it, and then enlarged the system fonts. everything seemed perfect. but recently, i installed matlab on ubuntu, and i found that matlab not fall in with the system fonts, the font in matlab has the original size and too small for me. i changed the size of font in code area by modifying ***File--Preferences***, but the fonts in menu bar and prompt windows are still too small for me. having searched the Internet for a long time, i found nothing help to change the fonts in such areas. can anyone give a hand to me? any help appreciated!

Comment: How `java` tag is related with your question?

Comment: @Andremoniy: because the interface of Matlab is written in Java.

Answer (score 1):

These commands will allow you to modify the font settings:

```
UIControl_FontSize_bak = get(0, 'DefaultUIControlFontSize');
set(0, 'DefaultUIControlFontSize', 18);
insdati = menu('Can you please help me?','Yes','No')
set(0, 'DefaultUIControlFontSize', UIControl_FontSize_bak);
```

This creates a list of available settings:

```
get(0, 'Default');
```